# BigTable to TensorFlow 2.x - Any connector?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

Is there a direct BigTable connector for TensorFlow 2.x ?

I haven't found any clear track of such package in the master branches of the Github repos [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) and [tensorflow_io](https://github.com/tensorflow/io/tree/master/tensorflow_io).
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support on Bigtable was started on `tfio v0.5.0` but was removed on `v0.13.0`. Here's the note:

> BigTable has been broken from the beginning, and was never maintained.
> In addition, there are lots of code duplication as it implment 6 datasets
> in C++ with very minimal difference. Due to the recent changes in TF upsteram
> API change, it gets harder and harder to even make it compile.

> This PR removes BigTable from the code tree. The plan is to add BigTable in the future
> with right implementation, ideally utilize the better maintained google cloud C++ big table API: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/tree/master/google/cloud/bigtable

Check their commit log: https://github.com/tensorflow/io/commit/f08f7954631cd13b3ace059dbc05f0b71dcd857d

Comment: Thanks ! Do you know if Tensorflow IO is directly supported by Google ? That sounds like a natural fit for their offering.

Comment: Tensorflow I/O is a [community led open source project](https://github.com/tensorflow/io#contributing). As such, the project depends on public contributions, bug-fixes, and documentation. There's no guarantee, but you can create a feature request on the repo by following this [sample template](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/30-feature-request.md)

Comment: Thanks - will do.